# Permalink to latest Eclipse 4.2 version

Tags: eclipse

In administering a few developer boxes, it would *extremely* useful to me to be able to rely on some sort of "permanent location" where I can expect the latest Eclipse 4.2 drop to reside.

Currently I am BeautifulSoup parsing the page and it is giving me this:

```
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.2-201302041200/eclipse-SDK-4.2.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
```

Could it be that there is really no way in the world to point to something like this:

```
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/latest_eclipse-SDK-4.2.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
```

with an accompanying (also permalink) page that would give me the shasum of the drop, so as to avoid re-downloading stuff that Squid is failing to detect as "serve from cache"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is fine for you to get them from EclipseSource instead of eclipse.org, you could take these links: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/03/11/fast-access-to-old-eclipse-releases/ They seem to be fixed (if you follow through the pages).

Answer (score 0):

The 4.2.2 release is the last release of the 4.2.x line. You can reference the URL you have safely. It will be good for many years. The only thing newer will be the next release series.